# What do the quantitative values for the colour ramp gradient for heatmap style in the layer properties for QGIS signify?

Tags: qgis, color, heat-map

I would like to understand whether any quantitative values can be extracted when using the heatmap style in the layer properties? I assume areas with colours related to 1 are areas which have the highest risk and those with 0 are at least risk, however what can be said about the values in between? For example, in the image here, what do colours above 0.5 in the plot signify?

[image]

Comment: Values in between have a mediocre risk. I feel like you don't really know what you want to ask, can you clarify?

Comment: I want to be able to give quantitative values along with the image of my heatmap, but not sure how the colour cutoff values relate to this. So If I have a delimited text layer over the top of the heatmap and chose to only select the points which lay within colours that were within the colour range 0.5-1, could I say that these selected points are in the areas which are within the top 50% most at risk?

Comment: I can't answer this question, since I don't know what your heat map represents.